# Mac OS X: What are the implications and consequences of executing "kill -9 writeconfig" from the console?

Tags: macos, mac, secure-erase

I am trying to delete an account and checked the "Erase home folder securely" option.

I now notice the process writeconfig is running about 100% CPU, and has been so for some 12 hours now.

Anybody know if killing this process will crap out my machine if I do it in the middle of deleting an account?

Thanks; any insight/advice is appreciated.

MacBook Air 13-inch, mid-2011, OS X Yosemite (10.10.3), 256GB SSD, 4GB RAM

Comment: Asked on another StackExchange several years ago: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30639/

Comment: Actually I'm asking something different. I want to know what are the consequences of issuing “kill -9 writeconfig”, which wasn't answered there.